# I want to split a sentence into words and get it to display vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what i have so far.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence".lower())
sentence = sentence.split()
print (sentence)
```

Current output:

```
enter a sentence hi my name is bob

['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'bob']
```

Desired output (without those big spaces)

```
hi

my

name

is

bob
```

I think it involves **for word in sentance** but im not sure

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
for word in sentence:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Would this print the characters line-by-line, or the words-line by line? I would think it would be `for word in sentence.split():`.

Comment: @MichaelMolter this is presumably to come after `sentence = sentence.split()`

Comment: I believe the OP has already done the split in their code, so I am assuming `sentence` is already split based on that.

Comment: Thanks so much i tried that but i put print(sentence

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `end` argument for `print` to get the spacing you desire from a single print statement. The default is a single newline: `'\n'`

```
for word in sentence:
    print(word, end="\n\n")
```

Edit: oops, missed the `out` in `without`

> Desired output (**without** those big spaces)

All the same, you can specify any end you want in Python3's print function. If you wanted to print it out as if it were a sentence, you could make the end character a space.

**Alternatively, you can use the `join` method of a string to join elements of an iterable to a string.**

```
print("\n".join(sentence))
#or more explicitly:
print("\n".join(word for word in sentence))
```